# how to handle root path request with node.js on firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm developing web system using firebase hosting + functions.
Inspite of specifying rewrite rules on firebase.json,
a part of routing doesn't work.

```
root/
　├ functions/
　│  ├index.js
　│  ├routes/
　│  │  └ index.js
　│  └views/
　│    ├ index.jade
　│    └ sub.jade
　└ public/
    └index.html // this is created by default. I don't want to use this.
```

This is my firebase.json

```
"rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "function": "app"
    }],
```

And this is node.js code.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

router.get('/subdir', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('sub');
});
```

result

```
https://myurl/ -> public/index.html is shown.(not handled on node.js)
https://myurl/ -> handled on node.js
```

Do you know how to handle root path request with node.js on firebase hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#hosting_priority_order .

> Priority order of Hosting responses
>
> The different Firebase Hosting configuration options described on this page can sometimes overlap. If there is a conflict, Hosting determines its response using the following priority order:
>
> 1. Reserved namespaces that begin with a /__/* path segment
> 2. Configured redirects
> 3. Exact-match static content
> 4. Configured rewrites
> 5. Custom 404 page
> 6. Default 404 page

Exact-match static content is high priority order than Configured rewrites.

So `https://myurl/` get static content `/index.html`.

Can you try remove public/index.html?

---

I tried. I can rewrite.

See https://github.com/zkohi/firebase-hosting-using-functions-samples .

And you should check https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions .

Comment: It worked when trying again. I do not know why the result is different from the last time, but it worked anyway.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a dummy folder that is **empty**. eg.: `dummyApiFolder`
2. Make a very simple cloud function. eg.

```
exports.bla = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    res.send("server bla");
});
```

3. Use the following hosting rules

```
    "hosting": {
        "target": "api",
        "public": "dummyApiFolder",
        "rewrites": [
            {
                "source": "**",
                "function": "bla"
            }
        ]
    }
```

3.1. `target` is only needed if you have set this up in your `.firebaserc` file

3.2. `"public": "dummyApiFolder",` is needed. Otherwise the CLI won't allow the deployment

Now **all** requests should get forwarded to `bla`.

The reason I'm advising to start with a simple cloud function is, `express` can be setup incorrectly. This can also give you an error, but you end up not knowing if it's a firebase issue or a code issue!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple! Just rename the `index.html` file in the public directory into some other name. Also, just in case: In the `firebase.json` file, Change the `public` property's value 
from `public` to `.`