# Using Firebase function as a proxy server

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

I built an app with  Vuejs which is hosted on firebase, I recently added dynamic rendering with rendertron to improve SEO, I'm hosting the rendertron on Heroku. The rendertron client work well.

In order to send requests coming from bots like googlebot to rendertron and recieve a compiled HTML file, I used firebase function, it checks for the user agent, if it's a bot then it sends it to the rendertron link, if it's not, it fetches the app and resend result.

Here's the function code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const url = require('url');
const app = express();

const appUrl = 'khbich.com';
const renderUrl = 'https://khbich-render.herokuapp.com/render';
function generateUrl(request){
  return url.format({
    protocol:request.protocol,
    host:appUrl,
    pathname:request.originalUrl
  });
}
function detectBot(userAgent){

  let bots = [
  "googlebot",
  "bingbot",
  "facebookexternalhit",
  "twitterbot",
  "linkedinbot",
  "facebot"

  ]
  const agent = userAgent.toLowerCase()
  for(let bot of bots){
    if(agent.indexOf(bot)>-1){
      console.log('bot-detected',bot,agent)
    }
  }
}


app.get('*', (req,res)=>{
  let isBot = detectBot(req.headers['user-agent']);
  if(isBot){
    let botUrl= generateUrl(req);
    fetch(`${renderUrl}/${botUrl}`)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body=>{
      res.set('Cache-Control','public','max-age=300','s-maxage=600')
      res.set('Vary','User-Agent');
      res.send(body.toString())
    })
  }
  else{
    fetch(`https://${appUrl}`)
    .then(res=>res.text())
    .then(body=>{
      res.send(body.toString())
    })
  }
});
```

I used the function as an entry point for firebase hosting, so it's invoked whenever someone enters the app.

I checked on the firebase dashboard to see if it's working, and I noticed that it crashed for exceeding the number of requests per 100 second quota, I don't have much users when I checked,  and the function invocations reached 370 calls in one minute.

I don't see why I had a large number of calls all at once, I'm thinking that maybe since I'm fetching the website if the user agent is not a bot, then the function is re-invoked causing an infinite loop of invocations, but I don't know if that's really why ?

If it's an infinite loop, how can I redirect users to their entered url without reinvoking the function ? will a redirect work ?

Comment: Shooting in the dark here but... have you tried adding the param `next` to `(req, res, next)`, and calling `next()` instead of calling `fetch`? Maybe that way the request can continue to firebase hosting, so the url is statically served?

Comment: Another thing you could try is to add `/index.html` to the URL, because [it looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272803/how-to-handle-root-path-request-with-node-js-on-firebase-hosting) if it matches a static file, it would skip the cloud function.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that ``fetch(`https://${appUrl}`)`` is retriggering the function. Instead of using that, just serve the content from file, e.g. `fs.readFileSync` and the like.

Comment: @yuriy636 Indeed `next` solve the problem of recursive call effect, however, when I go to some link in my website through the UI, it works like a charm, but if I reload it, I get an error from firebase function : `Cannot GET /link/some_stuff` , this happens online and locally through firebase serve, do you have an idea on what's causing such problem ?